# How to install a local module file with drush?

Tags: 7, drush

I have a local environment I am working on and I want to use drush to install a local file/module I have that was created by a exported feature. The reason I am not doing it with update manager is because its giving me a ftp error and rather than try to solve that, I would rather bypass it completely with drush (and since drush is faster anyway).

So basically I have my main site in www/var/mysite

And i have the exported feature module in my home directory / downloads.

So how do I get drush to upload and enable my local file to my drupal site?

Comment: With Drush, you could simply do `drush en -y views`, for example, and it would download the Views module.

Comment: `cd /var/www/mysite` then `drush en -y modulename`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already have the module / feature that you want to install on your local disk, simply copy the files to **DRUPAL_ROOT**/sites/all/modules.  Some folks also like to create "contrib", "custom" and "features" directories inside of "modules" to better organize their files.

Once you have your files in place, run `drush en featurename` to turn it on.